# Tiles con Struts2 y Maven

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, struts, struts2

Hola me encuentro aprendiendo Struts2 con maven, pero al configurar los Tiles, la consola me arroja una excepción y no logro entender que hace falta a la configuración básica, basándome en la documentación no encuentro solución alguna al error presentado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la configuración de mis archivos es:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb0bs.png)]

las acciones a procesar están de la siguiente manera en mi archivo LinkAction.java:

```
package co.com.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.*;

@Results({
    @Result(name = "welcomeResult", location = "welcomeTile", type = "tiles"),
    @Result(name = "personsResult", location = "personsTile", type = "tiles")
})

public class LinkAction extends ActionSupport{
    
    @Action(value = "welcomeAction")
    public String welcome(){
        return "welcomeResult";
    }
    
    @Action(value = "personsAction")
    public String persons(){
        return "personsResult";
    }
    
}
```

la configuración de mi archivo web.xml es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

la configuración del archivo tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="layout" template="/content/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Plantilla" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/content/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="main" value="/content/main.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/content/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/content/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    
    <definition name="welcomeTile" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Bienvenido"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/content/welcome.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    
    <definition na1me="personsTile" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Personas"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/content/persons.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

la configuración de mi plantilla layout.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"/></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td height="30" colspan="2">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="250">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="main" />
                </td>
                <td width="350">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="30" colspan="2">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

configuración del archivo struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <!--<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="co.com.actions" />-->
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="co.com.actions" />
    <!--<package name="default" extends="struts-default">-->
    <package name="co.com.actions" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        
        <action name="welcome" class="co.com.actions.LinkAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">welcome</result>
        </action>
        <action name="persons" class="co.com.actions.LinkAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">persons</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

en el archivo struts.xml, probe modificando algunas lineas como:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="co.com.actions" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
```

pero sin éxito alguno

Answer (score 0):

Parece que te faltan las dependencias en el POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${version.tiles}</version>
</dependency>
```